# CORS Error: “requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http…” etc

Tags: javascript, angular, express, cors

I am trying to run a simple application. I have an Express backend which returns a JSON string when visited at `localhost:4201/ticker`. When I run the server and make a request to this link from my Angular Service over `http`, I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:4201/ticker. Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

I read the following article: [Understanding and Using CORS](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/) and as stated, used the `cors` module with my express server. However, I am still getting the error as given above. Part of code is given below:

Server code:

```
private constructor(baseUrl: string, port: number) {
    this._baseUrl = baseUrl;
    this._port = port;
    this._express = Express();
    this._express.use(Cors());
    this._handlers = {};
    this._hInstance = new Handlers();
    this.initHandlers();
    this.initExpress();
}
private initHandlers(): void {
    // define all the routes here and map to handlers
    this._handlers['ticker'] = this._hInstance.ticker;
}
private initExpress(): void {
    Object.keys(this._handlers)
        .forEach((key) => {
            this._express.route(this._url(key))
                .get(this._handlers[key]);
        });
}
private _url(k: string): string {
    return '/' + k;
}
```

Here is the handler function:

```
ticker(req: Request, res: Response): void {
    Handlers._poloniex
        .getTicker()
        .then((d) => {
            return Filters.tickerFilter(d, Handlers._poloniex.getBases());
        })
        .then((fdata) => {

            //res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
            //res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.send(JSON.stringify(fdata));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
           this._logger.log([
                'Error: ' + err.toString(),
                'File: ' + 'handlers.class.ts',
                'Method: ' + 'ticker'
            ], true);
        });   
}
```

Here is my Angular Service:

```
export class LiveTickerService {

  private _baseUrl: string;
  private _endpoints: {[key:string]: string};

  constructor(
    private _http: Http
  ) {
    this._baseUrl = 'localhost:4201/';
     this._endpoints = {
       'ticker': 'ticker'
     };
   }

  getTickerData(): Observable<Response> {
    return this._http.get(this._baseUrl + this._endpoints['ticker'])
      .map(resp => resp.json())
  }

}
```

Here is how I am using my Service:

```
getTicker() {
  let a = new Array<{[key: string]: any}>();
  this._tickerService.getTickerData()
     .subscribe(
        data => {
          let parsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
          Object.keys(parsed)
            .forEach((k) => {
              a.push({k: parsed[k]});
            });
         this.data = a;
        },
        error => console.log(error.toString()),
        () => console.log('Finished fetching ticker data')
      );
  return this.data;
}
```

Answer (score 237, accepted):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:4201/ticker. Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

Any time you see that *“only supported for protocol schemes”* message, it almost certainly means you’ve just forgotten to put the `https` or `http` on the request URL in your code.

So in this case, the fix is to use the URL `http://localhost:4201/ticker` in your code here:

```
this._baseUrl = 'http://localhost:4201/';
```

…because without the `http://` there, `localhost:4201/ticker` isn’t really the URL you intend.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using just `localhost` and not `http://localhost`.

you need to include `http` or `https`

Comment: This answer does not add any new information compared to what  is already provided by the accepted answer above.