# JS How to send http get request to my express server?

Tags: jquery, express, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send a http get request  to my simple server written with js express the problem is that i dont know what should i put in url to connect to my server which will run local.
Second question how can i get value from the get request?
in this example "something" value send in request

server

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 4001;
app.get("/question",(req, res, next) => {
    res.send("something")
    console.log("got something")
})
app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log("working")
})
```

client

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.item').on('click', (element) =>{
        $.get(??????/question)
    })
})
```

Comment: Most likely `localhost:4001`.  Your local machine is commonly referenced by `localhost` or IP `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Taplar now i got such a error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:4001/cos' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.  can i do something with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS Error: “requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http…” etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258449/cors-error-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-http-etc)

Comment: @Taplar i did as they suggested (added http:// in front) and now i got such an error: GET http://localhost:8080/some net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the client is not a part of the express app and assuming you have run dev mode.

`http://localhost:4001/question`

**CORS Issue**

You would encounter cors since the client is not part of the express application.

So you must include the following code your express app.

```
const cors = require('cors'); // npm i -s cors - to install it in your express app
app.use(cors());
```

To filter origins and do more stuff you refer the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)