# access to xmlhttprequest from origin http://localhost:3000 has been blocked due to CORS policy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

i have set a front and a backend for an app i am developing and i want to test http requests sent from front to back while these two run in localhost.

Code sending request using React:

```
 async componentDidMount(){
           const {data: posts}= await axios.get("localhost:8765/...");
       }
```

Code for app server using Express:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
require('./routes/...')(app)

app.listen(8765, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 8765.")
})
```

Front end is running on localhost 3000.

This is the error i get:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8765/...' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol 
schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

i have tried various solutions i found online like:

```
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));
```

or:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');

    
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    
    next();
});
```

or:

```
app.use(cors())
```

Nothing seems to work though,i still get the same error,and i've been stuck in this for quite a while.Any ideas?

Comment: the basic reason is that you cannot make requests via JavaScript from one domain:port, to another. There are however ways to allow this.

Comment: 1. Generate app using [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/) and add `"proxy": "http://localhost:8765"` to your `package.json` file. This will proxy requests, ignoring CORS issues.
2. Start up Chrome with `--disable-web-security`, while this will work, I don't really recommend doing it
3. Configure your local server to allow CORS, there are many examples of this e.g. https://www.positronx.io/express-cors-tutorial/

The first option is easiest but you can try setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin, '*'`

Comment: Your error is basically because you forgot to add the protocol `http` in your `axios.get` method call. The request will be `axios.get('http://localhost:8765/...')`.

Comment: For reference check this post here as I faced the same issue before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258449/cors-error-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-http-etc

Answer (score 1):

Simply use  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');