# How to get the users data after being logged in

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, jwt, cors

I want to get the data of the user who is logged in and display it on his profile, the problem is the data that I am getting is from all the users that are registered in the table, here is the request.

```
const [profile, setProfile] = useState();
 async function fetchProfile() {
    const res = await fetch("localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/user", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    });
    if (res.ok) {
      const json = await res.json();
      setProfile(json);
    } else {
      router.push("/auth/login");
    }
  }
```

I have a specific endpoint to get only one user but for that I need the users id.

I tried to include credentials:"include" in the request but I am having issues with CORS.

Comment: I doubt you're getting a CORS issue. In all likelihood, `fetch("localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/user" ...` fails because you forgot the `http://` bit in the queried URL.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the request in the dev tools? What exact error you are getting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS Error: “requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http…” etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258449/cors-error-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-http-etc)