# Access to manifest at /manifest.json from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy. React production build

Tags: reactjs, npm, fetch-api, npm-build

I built the react app for production using the following command :

```
npm run build
```

but getting the following error while running index.html. What could be issue here and how can I resolve it ? (screenshot attached)

Console error :

> Access to manifest at
> 'file:///Users/nanditasingh/Documents/workspace/dashboard-app/manifest.json'
> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin
> requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
> isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpQyS.png)

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.f8df3b0f.js"></script>
    <link href="./static/css/main.1665f4d8.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS Error: “requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http…” etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258449/cors-error-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-http-etc)