# I got CORS error when trying to do a request in my app in Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, cors, postman

This is the error that I had faced before when requesting in localhost, and I solved it using proxy config in Angular.

So as I was using a custom proxy, I had to remove that proxy-config from my Angular app before deploying it in Heroku, because if I don't do this, the deployment app doesn't work.

This is the CORS error:

[cors error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALSVm.png)

in postman the localhost request works if I nodemon the node server so I can say there's no error in my api

[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J445L.png)

but if using the request given by heroku in postman I get this html response

[heroku link in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WdG3.png)

tbh I don't know what's going on, because I'm doing a course of Angular and these errors are not supposed to appair, tkank you guys :)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong: the URL you're requesting lacks a scheme/protocol.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS Error: “requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http…” etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258449/cors-error-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-http-etc)

Answer (score 0):

Your web server should allow `cors` for you application.

If you server is written with NodeJS, take look at the [Cors package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Then In NodeJS project, install it:

```bash
npm install cors
```

Then modify a bit your listener:

```js
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

Make sure `app.use(cors())` to be before any other middleware

Comment: unfortunately I already did that at the beginning of the course :/